# Realm android map date field using createObjectFromJson()

Tags: android, json, realm, inputstream

Started working on Realm database(Android), I am calling wcf service which response is as,

```
{
   "ProductId": 1,
  "ProductCategory": " CategorY_result",
  "ProductName": "Admission",
  "Priority": "High",
  "EnteredBy": null,
  "EnteredDate": "/Date(1224043200000)/",
}
```

and model for this as,

```
 public class Product extends RealmObject
 {
  @PrimaryKey
  private long ProductId;

  private String ProductCategory;
private String ProductName;
private String Typeofcollege;
private String Priority;
 private Date EnteredDate;    // is it mapped to Date directly ?
}
```

I want Date data type for EnteredDate field, i am doing steam parsing using 
createObjectFromJson() method

```
realm.createObjectFromJson(Product.class,inputStream);
```

but getting null value for EnteredDate. how can tackle this

Comment: What are you using for getting data from web. Any library or simple HttpClient?

Comment: HttpUrlConnection

Comment: Manual mapping is your friend, that way you can throw away this `NotCamelCase` field name convention

Comment: I have answered the question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WCF services supply Dates over JSON in a strange format, you have to format it by writing your own serialisation and deserialisations code (i.e. "/Date(12345678989+0000)/")

Below in the code snippet I have defined how to write an object into Realm Db using **Gson** Lib to parse your **WCF date format into java date format.**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Realm
        Realm.init(this);

        // Get a Realm instance for this thread
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        //Gson instance for date matching
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new NetDateTimeAdapter()).create();

        //example of json you want to match
        String stringObj = "{\n" +
                "      \"ProductId\": 1,\n" +
                "      \"ProductCategory\": \" CategorY_result\",\n" +
                "      \"ProductName\": \"Admission\",\n" +
                "      \"Priority\": \"High\",\n" +
                "      \"EnteredBy\": null,\n" +
                "      \"EnteredDate\": \"/Date(1224043200000)/\"\n" +
                "     }";

        //Using gson lib parsing json into gson into WcfObject
        Product object = gson.fromJson(stringObj, Product.class);


        //write the object into realm
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.insertOrUpdate(object);
        realm.commitTransaction();

        RealmResults<Product> result = realm.where(Product.class).findAll();

        for (Product obj : result) {
            //printing it to see weather it is working or not
            Log.e("value", obj.toString());
        }

    }


    private static class NetDateTimeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Date> {
        @Override
        public Date read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
            if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                reader.nextNull();
                return null;
            }
            Date result = null;
            String str = reader.nextString();
            str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
                try {
                    result = new Date(Long.parseLong(str));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter writer, Date value) throws IOException {
            // Nah..
        }
    }
}
```

Product class code

```
import java.util.Date;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class Product extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        private int ProductId;
        private String ProductCategory;
        private String ProductName;
        private String EnteredBy;
        private Date EnteredDate;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
                return "WcfObject{" +
                        "ProductId=" + ProductId +
                        ", ProductCategory='" + ProductCategory + '\'' +
                        ", ProductName='" + ProductName + '\'' +
                        ", EnteredBy='" + EnteredBy + '\'' +
                        ", EnteredDate=" + EnteredDate.toString() +
                        '}';
        }
}
```

All the above given code is described with the comment. Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: thanks for answer, i am trying to insert InputStream directly to database (RealmObject), using  realm.createObjectFromJson method. i dont know what happand but after clean and Building the project its working now

Comment: It might be working but if you are not converting the date it will end up with null value. If my answer is okay. Please mark it as answer to your question.